# What are the fibers and small droplets on the surface of dividing HeLa cells in the figure?

Tags: cell-biology

I did some literature searching but could not find any info probably because I did not know how people name them.

[image]

The figure is from the wikipedia entry [HeLa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeLa#Chromosome_number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [microvilli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microvillus) and [blebs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleb_(cell_biology)).